# Table is not rendering until searchbar is populated in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, filter

I have a table of data that I map through. I need all the data available to be viewable when the page renders, but the search function I currently have set up, only renders out table cells that match the input. How can I have all the data present and then filter out item only when the search bar is being used?

this is my state and what I use to filter

```
  let [filter, setFilter] = useState();
  let [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([]);
  const handleChange = event => {
    setFilter(event.target.value);
  };
```

This is the useEffect I use to do the actual filtering

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (props.data !== undefined) {
      const results = props.data.filter(
        resp =>
          (resp.first_name || "").toLowerCase().includes(filter) ||
          (resp.last_name || "").toLowerCase().includes(filter)
      );
      setFilteredResults(results);
    }
  }, [filter, props.data]);
```

this is the input for the search bar

```
     <input
           type="text"
            className="searchField"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={filter || ""}
          />
```

and finally here is the big bad table itself

```
 filteredResults.map(data => {
              return (
                <tr key={data.id}>
                  <td>
                    <div className="mobileBox">
                      {data.first_name !== ""
                        ? data.first_name + " " + data.last_name
                        : "--None--"}
                    </div>
                  </td>

                  <td className="normalView">
                    {props.departments.map(department => {
                      return department.id === data.default_department_id ? (
                        <div key={department.id}> {department.name}</div>
                      ) : (
                        ""
                      );
                    })}
                  </td>
                  <td className="normalView">
                    {data.status ? "Active" : "Disabled"}
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <i
                      className="fas fa-pencil-alt"
                      onClick={() => handleEdit(data)}
                    ></i>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })
          )}
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think the issue is `props.data` in useEffect dependency array. Try to remove it.

Comment: I dont think that is the issue, two reasons, the first being is my Linter complains loudly when I take it off, and B after writing this question I realized I didnt make ```filter``` a string, and when I did so most (but not all of the data) showed up

Comment: Don't filter anything if the search bar is empty..

Comment: Also you don't need a separate state for filtered results, just filter `props.data` in your table